# OpenStack Swift List Columns

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

How can I have the OpenStack Swift cli list the columns in the output for the swift list like `swift list --lh`?

I currently see the following

```
user@server1:~$ swift list --lh      
164006  30G 2020-03-28 02:32:33 backups1
54637 8.1G 2019-10-09 03:00:02 backups2
46549 1.8G 2020-02-26 21:30:03 backups3
 258K  40G
```

I'd be interested in any official documentation that would state the columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `openstack container list` command produces different output that potentially has what you want:

```
$ openstack container list --long
+------------+-------+-------+
| Name       | Bytes | Count |
+------------+-------+-------+
| container0 |     0 |     0 |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

You can ask for output in CSV, JSON, YAML, or raw values (using the `-f` option), and you can request specific columns using `-c`:

```
$ openstack container list --long -f yaml -c Name -c Count
- Count: 0
  Name: container0
```

Comment: The `swift` client has an option `--json`, which also prints headers.

Comment: @berndbausch do you know when that was added? I don't seem to have it in `python-swiftclient 3.7.0`

Comment: @RyanGates It looks like I misunderstood the code. Sorry. This option exists, but only for the [capabilities subcommand](https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/latest/cli/index.html#swift-capabilities). It's a bit surprising that it has not been extended to other subcommands.